# Get distances in miles for 2 longitudes or 2 latitudes only

Tags: java, c#, google-maps, math

I'm trying to modify a formula to get the distances between 2 lat or 2 lon only which will translate into x, y coordinates.

The code/formula below (Haversine) gives the hypotenuse (direct distance between 2 points with an angle)

However I want to get x, y coordinates as well using only the latitudes & longitudes. Since these are straight lines, the angle should not matter.

One way would be to set both latitudes to zero - which will give me the longitude distance (and vice versa) - however it will require me to call the same function 3 times:

1 for direct distance, 1 for x distance, 1 for y distance

Is there any way that I can amend the code below to calculate all 3 at once efficiently and return it as an array [x_dis, y_dis, direct_dist]

```
    private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }

        return (dist);
    }


    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }


    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: @Abion47 - Sorry , i added both in case someone had a c# version which is very similar - updated the topic title

Comment: Your idea of "x distance" is wrong: it depends on the latitude. Furthermore, do you want to run along that given latitude when calculating the "x distance" or take the shortest distance there?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see would be to create a function that calls it three times and returns each value.

```
private static double[] getAlldistances(double lat1, double lat2, double long1, double long2, string unit){
    double latDistance = distance(lat1, 0, lat2, 0, unit);
    double longDistance = distance(0, long1, 0, long2, unit);
    double directDistance = distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, unit);
    return double int[3] {latDistance, longDistance, directDistance};
}
```

This should use your existing function without an issue. By setting the long or lat to 0 for both points we are able to work out the distance between just the lats or the longs. The code is untested and should be treated as Pseudo code.